# Function not called on hidden input value is changed Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the values of all the hidden input fields and find the sum.
Hidden field is of class **mytotal**. Below is the code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
     <label for="brnos[]" class="control-label" style="width:100%">BR-NO</label>
     <input class="form-control mybrands" type="text" style="width:100%;text-align: center;" name="brnos[]" autocomplete="off" required>
     <div id="brList" style="width:auto;"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
     <label for="cases[]" class="control-label" style="width:100%">Cases</label>
     <input id="cases" class="form-control mycases" type="number" style="width:100%;text-align: center;" name="cases[]" value="0" autocomplete="off" required>
     <input class="form-control mytotal" type="hidden" style="width:100%;text-align: center;" name="mytotal" value="0">
 </div>
</div>
```

I use a function to set the value of my hidden field using an ajax function and it works fine. Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var doc;
        $(document).on("change", ".mycases", function() {
            doc = $(this);
            var value = doc.parent().parent('div').find('.mybrands').val();
            var cases = doc.val();
            var total_cases = $("#total_cases");
            if(value!='')
            {
                var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('origin.find') }}",
                    type: 'POST',                  
                    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN,value:value},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                       doc.parent('div').find('.mytotal').val(data.output*cases);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I tried to alert the value of **.mytotal** after changing its value inside ajax function and it shows the expected value.But when i call another ajax function to find the sum of the values of inputs that have class "mytotal" it is never called. Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("change", ".mytotal", function() {
            var sum = 0;
            $(".mytotal").each(function(){
                sum += +$(this).val();
                window.alert(sum);
            });
        });
    });
```

So instead of making it hidden field, I made it as type="number" and when I change the value of that field manually the function is called. Why is this happening? I want to make this field hidden and the function to be called when its value is changed. How to solve this? Please help!

Comment: At a glance, `doc.parent().parent('div')` seems off. Chaining `.parent()` can be problematic; consider `.closest('.row')`, which, while moving up in the DOM, will find the element's closest `class="row"`

Comment: ohhhhk ! Wat about the issue I have?

Comment: Still reading :P If you do a `console.log(doc.parent('div').find('.mytotal').length)` what do you get? Also, `.val()` won't trigger a change unless you do `.val(...).trigger("change")` (I think)

Comment: for now i get the length as 1

Comment: That's good, did you try adding `.trigger("change");` ? That _should_ trigger the `on("change"...)` listener.

Comment: I believe @TimLewis's second point above correctly identifies the source of confusion. The `change` event only fires if **A)** the *user* changes the value of the input, or **B)** You manually fire the event yourself by calling `.change()` or `.trigger("change")`.

Comment: Yes it worked !!! thanks ... .trigger("change) is the solution. :)

Comment: Answer it.. i will upvote it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a `.on("change", ...)` function is what's known as a listener, that handles when something is "changed". In you code, you're correctly changing the value with

```
doc.parent('div').find('.mytotal').val(data.output*cases);
```

But this doesn't actually fire the event that is handled by your listener.

To correctly handle this, all you need to do is add a `.trigger()` function after your `.val()` update:

```
doc.parent('div').find('.mytotal').val(data.output*cases).trigger("change");
```